# Position a Bones head in editmode in global position

Tags: armature, bones, edit-mode

I want to absolutely perfectly position my Bone's head position, fitting to the Mesh vertex position. I just wanted to copy and paste the vertex position to the bone's head position.
Problem is, the bones have completely different positions in edit mode than the vertexes in edit mode.
Can I somehow change the positioning of the bones or maybe the whole armature to global position?

Or is there another way of perfectly positioning a bones head to the position of a vertex?

I found a solution for everyone seeking for an answer.
Set the 3D cursor to the selected vertex and move the bone head to the 3D cursor via spacebar search functions!
like:
selection to cursor and
cursor to selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 3D cursor for this is a quite classical way, but there is an easier method, using snapping:

[image]

Using 3D cursor is useful, though. For example, when you need to snap at the center of a circular shape.

Comment: While this also works, I have noticed that the position of the bone ends up being a few millimeters off the vertices, which makes it unusable for me as I really want it to be perfect. The cursor selection and selection to cursor method takes a bit more time, but gives me more precision. So, thank you for your contribution anyway.

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled snap to vertex, (face by default)